# MongoDB 3.0.5 keeps crashing on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: mongodb

I am having a problem with running MongoDB on Windows.  To give a little background the server was running MongoDB 2.6.4 and was crashing every few days.  I upgraded to MongoDB 3.0.5 and switched to the WiredTiger storage engine.  The server is still crashing every few days. The logs are below.

The database is only 235MB in size total??

```
2015-10-05T13:00:53.640Z I QUERY    [conn2003] query mydb.streams.masterdata query: { _id: { $gt: 111429 } } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:17396581220 ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:8038 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:63 nreturned:0 reslen:20 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 128 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 64 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 64 } } } 108ms
2015-10-05T13:00:54.050Z I QUERY    [conn2013] query mydb.streams.event query: { _id: { $gt: 39 }, type: { $in: [ "requestcallout" ] } } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:78188012779 ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:42 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:20 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } 105ms
2015-10-05T13:00:54.076Z I QUERY    [conn2003] query mydb.streams.masterdata query: { _id: { $gt: 111429 } } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:19195520112 ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:8038 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:62 nreturned:0 reslen:20 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 126 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 63 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 63 } } } 157ms
2015-10-05T13:00:55.314Z I CONTROL  [conn2011] *** unhandled exception 0xC00000FD at 0x00007FF6D3165F77, terminating
2015-10-05T13:00:55.314Z I CONTROL  [conn2011] *** stack trace for unhandled exception:
2015-10-05T13:00:55.422Z I CONTROL  [conn2011] Stack trace failed, SymInitialize failed with error 8
2015-10-05T13:00:55.422Z I -        [conn2011] 
2015-10-05T13:00:55.428Z I CONTROL  [conn2011] writing minidump diagnostic file C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.2015-10-05T13-00-55.mdmp
2015-10-05T13:00:55.490Z I CONTROL  [conn2011] failed to create minidump : errno:-2147024888 Not enough storage is available to process this command.
2015-10-05T13:00:55.490Z I CONTROL  [conn2011] *** immediate exit due to unhandled exception
2015-10-05T13:55:51.274Z I CONTROL  ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
```

Answer (score 1):

0xC00000FD is a Stack Overflow exception. You need to raise a bug with Mongo DB developers.

The lack of storage error is probably a red herring, it refers to the minidump writing rather than the underlying MongoDB problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough disk storage?

I see the following comment
`Not enough storage is available to process this command`

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue got resolve Cause I am getting this issue in MongoDB 3.2 version.

```
2019-09-20T18:30:01.308+0530 I COMMAND  [conn1057] command ReconDB_14_02.HST_RecData_910 command: getMore { getMore: 240951836618, collection: "HST_RecData_910" } cursorid:240951836618 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1406 nreturned:393 reslen:2352906 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2814 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1407 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1407 } } } protocol:op_query 12738ms 
2019-09-20T18:30:04.944+0530 I CONTROL  [conn1057] Stack trace failed, SymInitialize failed with error 3765269347 
2019-09-20T18:30:04.944+0530 F -        [conn1057] out of memory.
```